# Class Diagram - repeat class in modules?

Tags: oop, uml

I've got a question about the repetition of classes between modules.
I had a large module with 24 classes and divide it into three classes with 8. But there is a class ("users") who appears in two of the modules. I can repeat it? And I need to put the attributes in both modules?
And what is the maximum ideal for classes in a module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Practically speaking: In UML, you do can describe a class / or object many times. And, you don't have to show all members (properties).

The ideal way to describe classes & relationships, is that each class is contained by a package, but, can be referenced (have some kind of relation) with other classes, either in the same package or different package.

The following diagrams are, in practical terms ok, and are several ways to describe the same thing in U.M.L. Im trying not to confuse you, with many diagrams.

The whole idea, is that in U.M.L, you may have several choices to describe or model the same idea.

**Fig 1. Example fully described classes within same package.**

```
...................................................................................
..+--------------------+...........................................................
..|..Streams...........|...........................................................
..+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+.
..|..............................................................................|.
..|.+----------------------------------+....+----------------------------------+.|.
..|.|            StreamClass           |....|          ReaderClass             |.|.
..|.+----------------------------------+....+----------------------------------+.|.
..|.| [#] void Read()     <<abstract>> |....| [+] void Read()     <<override>> |.|.
..|.| [#] void Write()    <<abstract>> +<---+ [+] bool CanRead()  <<override>> |.|.
..|.| [+] bool CanRead()  <<virtual>>  |....| [+] bool CanWrite() <<override>> |.|.
..|.| [+] bool CanWrite() <<virtual>>  |....| [+] bool CanRead()  <<virtual>>  |.|.
..|.+----------------------------------+....+----------------------------------+.|.
..|..............................................................................|.
..+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+.
...................................................................................
```

**Fig 2. Example classes within same package, omitting unnecesary members**

```
....................................................................................
..+--------------------+............................................................
..|..Streams...........|............................................................
..+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+.
..|...............................................................................|.
..|.+----------------------------------+....+----------------------------------+..|.
..|.|            StreamClass           |....|          ReaderClass             |..|.
..|.+----------------------------------+....+----------------------------------+..|.
..|.| [#] void Read()     <<abstract>> |....| [+] void Read()     <<override>> |..|.
..|.| [#] void Write()    <<abstract>> +<---+ [+] bool CanRead()  <<override>> |..|.
..|.| [+] bool CanRead()  <<virtual>>  |....| [+] bool CanWrite() <<override>> |..|.
..|.| [+] bool CanWrite() <<virtual>>  |....+----------------------------------+..|.
..|.+----------------------------------+..........................................|.
..|...............................................................................|.
..+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+.
....................................................................................
```

**Fig 3. Example classes in different packages**

```
...................................................................................
.+--------------------+...................+--------------------+...................
.|..Streams...........|...................|..Readers...........|...................
.+--------------------+-----------------+.+--------------------+-----------------+.
.|......................................|.|..|...................................|.
.|.+----------------------------------+.|.|.+----------------------------------+.|.
.|.|            StreamClass           |.|.|.|          ReaderClass             |.|.
.|.+----------------------------------+.|.|.+----------------------------------+.|.
.|.| [#] void Read()     <<abstract>> |.|.|.| [+] void Read()     <<override>> |.|.
.|.| [#] void Write()    <<abstract>> +<----+ [+] bool CanRead()  <<override>> |.|.
.|.| [+] bool CanRead()  <<virtual>>  |.|.|.| [+] bool CanWrite() <<override>> |.|.
.|.| [+] bool CanWrite() <<virtual>>  |.|.|.+----------------------------------+.|.
.|.+----------------------------------+.|.|......................................|.
.|......................................|.|......................................|.
.+--------------------------------------+.+--------------------------------------+..
...................................................................................
```

Sometimes, packages, are omitted in the class diagrams, or are consider to be in the same package.

**Fig 4. Example fully described classes without packages.**

```
................................................................................
..+----------------------------------+....+----------------------------------+..
..|            StreamClass           |....|          ReaderClass             |..
..+----------------------------------+....+----------------------------------+..
..| [#] void Read()     <<abstract>> |....| [+] void Read()     <<override>> |..
..| [#] void Write()    <<abstract>> +<---+ [+] bool CanRead()  <<override>> |..
..| [+] bool CanRead()  <<virtual>>  |....| [+] bool CanWrite() <<override>> |..
..| [+] bool CanWrite() <<virtual>>  |....+----------------------------------+..
..+----------------------------------+..........................................
................................................................................
```

And, finally, sometimes each class is fully described with its container packaged, plus a diagram, where only relations are displayed. The next 3 figures represent 3 complementary diagrams.

**Fig 5.1 Single class example.**

```
...........................................
..+--------------------+...................
..|..Streams...........|...................
..+--------------------+-----------------+.
..|......................................|.
..|.+----------------------------------+.|.
..|.|            StreamClass           |.|.
..|.+----------------------------------+.|.
..|.| [#] void Read()     <<abstract>> |.|.
..|.| [#] void Write()    <<abstract>> |.|.
..|.| [+] bool CanRead()  <<virtual>>  |.|.
..|.| [+] bool CanWrite() <<virtual>>  |.|.
..|.+----------------------------------+.|.
..|......................................|.
..+--------------------------------------+.
...........................................
```

**Fig 5.2 Single class example.**

```
...........................................
..+--------------------+...................
..|..Readers...........|...................
..+--------------------+-----------------+.
..|......................................|.
..|.+----------------------------------+.|.
..|.|            ReaderClass           |.|.
..|.+----------------------------------+.|.
..|.| [#] void Write()    <<abstract>> |.|.
..|.| [#] void Read()     <<override>> |.|.
..|.| [+] bool CanRead()  <<override>> |.|.
..|.| [+] bool CanWrite() <<override>> |.|.
..|.+----------------------------------+.|.
..|......................................|.
..+--------------------------------------+.
...........................................
```

**Fig 5.3 Example Relations among classes.**

```
................................................................................
..+----------------------------------+....+----------------------------------+..
..|            StreamClass           +<---+          ReaderClass             |..
..+----------------------------------+....+----------------------------------+..
................................................................................
```

**Summary**

Remember that U.M.L. is a guide, not an strict path.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer UMLcat. UML can reuse the same classifiers in more than one class diagram. I mean that for many years UML was related to graphical views and sometimes inside the same view all the project classifiers.

The UML metamodeling approach is to simply create an UML model which is live synchronized with the diagrams. In many tools you have mappers between graphical presentation and model. For example with Eclipse  you have the graphical mapper GMF which call the model mapper EMF which then create an UML model. It is therefore impossible to live synchronized the UML view with the uml model stored on your hard disk in xmi format.

Omondo EclipseUML have launched this metamodedl initiative few year ago. It allows you to create as many diagrams which are live synchronized with your UML model on disk saved immediately into XMI UML 2.3 format. You can therefore reuse the same classifier in different views because all the model logic is in the modedl saved on disk and live synchronize.

The round trip engineering is not only between code and model but deeper between model and metamodel. It gives full power to UML !!

Comment: I'll check Omondo, seems promising. I actually design most of my daily work models in LibreOffice, instead of existing tools, due to the fact, that doesn't allow to do many things, that U.M.L. suppouse to do...